Upper bound on the spectral norm of a matrix with zeroed entries far from the diagonal
Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ matrix (it can be considered symmetric/Hermitian if it is simpler but a general result would be nice) and define the following $n \times n$ circulant matrix
$$
C = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \dots & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
\vdots &&& \ddots & \ddots && \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 &&&& \ddots & \ddots && \ddots & 1 \\
0 & \ddots &&&& \ddots & \ddots && 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots &&&& \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 && \ddots & \ddots &&&& \ddots & 0 \\
1 & \ddots && \ddots & \ddots &&&& 1 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots && \ddots & \ddots &&& \vdots \\
1 & \dots & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & \dots & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
That is, $C = \operatorname{circ}(c_0, \ldots, c_{n - 1})$ with $c_i = 1$ if $i \leqslant L - 1$ or $i \geqslant n - L + 1$ and $c_i = 0$ otherwise. The parameter $L$ controls the size of the band around the diagonal (there are $2 L - 1$ ones per line/column).
I am interested in the matrix $M \odot C$ where $\odot$ is the entry-wise (or Hadamard) product. $[M \odot C]_{i, j} = M_{i, j}$ if $C_{i, j} = 1$ and $0$ otherwise. In particular, how does the entry-wise product with $C$ changes the spectral norm ?
From various simulations, I have observed that most of the time, $\lVert M \odot C \rVert \leqslant \lVert M \rVert$ but this is not true in general since I have found some examples for which $\lVert M \odot C \rVert > \lVert M \rVert$ but the difference $\lVert M \odot C \rVert - \lVert M \rVert$ is always small. Can we prove an upper bound $\lVert M \odot C \rVert \leqslant \alpha \lVert M \rVert$ where $\alpha$ is a constant (e.g., $2$) ?
Here is an example of a symmetric matrix $M$ such that $\lVert M \odot C \rVert > \lVert M \rVert$ with $n = 4$ and $L = 2$:
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
2.85 &  0.93 &  0.76 & -0.5 \\
0.93 &  4.16 & -1.31 &  0.24 \\
0.76 & -1.31 &  2.44 & -0.21 \\
-0.5 &  0.24 & -0.21 &  2.55
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad \lVert M \rVert \simeq 4.99866, \qquad \lVert M \odot C \rVert \simeq 5.16670.
$$
The best upper bound I can actually prove is quite disappointing: $\lVert M \odot C \rVert \leqslant \lVert M \odot C \rVert_F \leqslant \lVert M \rVert_F \leqslant \sqrt{n} \lVert M \rVert$ where $\lVert \cdot \rVert_F$ is the Frobenius norm. If $\alpha$ grows with $n$, I suspect it would grow much slower than $\sqrt{n}$.
Let me add some information which could be useful for the problem.

I am not interested in the case where $L \ll n$. The parameters $L$ and $n$ can be considered proportional (with the constraint $2 L - 1 \leqslant n$).
The eigendecomposition of $C$ is $F \Psi F^*$ where $F$ is the DFT matrix and $\Psi = \operatorname{Diag}(\psi_0, \ldots, \psi_{n - 1})$ with $\psi_k = D_{L-1}(\frac{2 k \pi}{n})$ where $D_{L - 1}$ is the Dirichlet kernel.
The $L^1$ norm of $D_{L - 1}$ behaves as $\frac{4}{\pi^2} \log L + O(1)$ so $\frac{1}{n} \sum_k \lvert \psi_k \rvert = O(\log L)$. Something like $\lVert M \odot C \rVert \leqslant \alpha \log n \lVert M \rVert$ would already be satisfying.


I actually found a satisfying answer which coincides with the result of Luis G but in a more direct and simple way.
Using the eigendecomposition $C = F \Psi F^*$, we have
$$
M \odot C = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \psi_k (M \odot F_{\cdot, k + 1} F_{\cdot, k + 1}^*) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \psi_k \operatorname{Diag}(F_{\cdot, k + 1}) M \operatorname{Diag}(F_{\cdot, k + 1})^*
$$
where $F_{\cdot, k + 1}$ is the vector corresponding to the $(k + 1)$-th column of $F$ and $\operatorname{Diag}(F_{\cdot, k + 1})$ is the diagonal matrix such that $[\operatorname{Diag}(F_{\cdot, k + 1})]_{i, i} = F_{i, k + 1}$. Then,
$$
\lVert M \odot C \rVert \leqslant \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \lvert \psi_k \rvert \lVert \operatorname{Diag}(F_{\cdot, k + 1}) \rVert^2 \rVert M \rVert = \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \lvert \psi_k \rvert \right) \lVert M \rVert
$$
since $\lVert \operatorname{Diag}(F_{\cdot, k + 1}) \rVert^2 = \max_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n} \lvert F_{i, k} \rvert^2 = \frac{1}{n}$. Finally, from the properties of the Dirichlet kernel, we know that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \lvert \psi_k \rvert = O(\log L)$ therefore
$$
\lVert M \odot C \rVert \leqslant \alpha \log n \lVert M \rVert
$$
for some constant $\alpha > 0$.
